# Because Backblaze accounts only provide one B2 Cloud Storage application key, how should you handle using B2 for multiple app?

Tags: web-applications, cloud, object-storage, backblaze

Coming from services like AWS S3 and Google Cloud Storage, I'm used to being able to use individual access accounts (like IAM on AWS and service accounts on Google Cloud) for individual apps. I always thought this made sense, that it was good practice when it comes to security and making sure problems with one app's cloud services don't affect another.

However, Backblaze only offers you one application key per account. Does this mean that we should create individual Backblaze accounts if we create multiple apps, and use one account per app? Or use multiple accounts per app to have unique keys for testing, dev, prod etc? I'm curious if anyone's had any experience with B2 and could offer some advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer to my problem. I read further into the docs and found that the application key given to your account is a master key that can create other keys through their API. So you would create other application keys for the individual apps, specifying the access they should have as you create them. Kind of a DIY IAM system.

Comment: Hey Matt, it's been a while, but could you 'accept' your answer so it shows the nice green checkmark? It makes it more clear that the question has been correctly answered. Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Worth noting though that while it was a correct answer at the time, Backblaze has since changed how keys work, and this may not be the best solution anymore.